# Storing Blob of 100 MB in size in apache ignite

Tags: blob, ignite

We need a durable cache for storing blobs which are as follows
1. The blob could be from 1 MB to 1 GB.
2. We do not have to index the blog document.
3. The cache entry should be durable in case of node failure. So we need replication and partitioning.
4. There should be a write-behind hook so that we can use external data storage to write data.
5. Very High transaction. We would like to run like 100+ nodes .

Can someone comment on requirement number 1. I am concerned if Apache Ignite is right choice for the same.

Comment: Do you plan to modify the entries?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think storing such large blobs directly will perform well. I would suggest splitting them into multiple chunks, say 1MB each, and storing them in IgniteCache using putAll(...) method. You should make sure that all chunks will end up in the same partition by using [affinity collocation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation).

For the write-behind functionality you should configure CacheStore. If you follow the above design, then it will result in invocation of the CacheStore.writeAll(...) method. You should plugin your own CacheStore which will properly reassemble the blob in the "writeAll(...)" method and persist it to database.

More on CacheStore, write-behind, and 3rd party persistence here:
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store

Answer (score 0):

A late reply, but it feels like the blob you are storing could be treated as a file as well. In that case you could consider the Ignite File System feature.

In one of the projects I am involved in we used to operate with file-drop locations to share large blob-data between services: those blobs range in size from a few kilobytes to a half a terabyte.
Especially the combination of many small files and operations on large files caused problems. But since we were in control on how the blobs were serialized, we decided to operate with IGFS for the shared blobs.

Performance is better than the shared file-locations we were using, but this is likely only in part caused by IGFS itself: the uniform way of writing and accessing the blobs helped as well (the environment is a mixed set of Windows and Linux services, which is a bit of a headache for traditional file-shares anyway).

A good starting point on the IGFS feature can be found here:
https://ignite.apache.org/features/igfs.html

I hope this helps.